# regex that covers multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, parsing, pcre

I would like to extract the data from the following sample txt

```
START
A: 567 B:345
C: 345 D:485


START
A: 345 B:267
C: 980 D:054
```

I'm using this regex with no positive results:

```
$regex = '~'
       . '^(?P<header>.*START:.*)$'
       //. '^(.*A: \d{3} B: \d{3}.*)$'
       //. '(.*C: \d{3} D: \d{3}.*)$'
       . '~m'
;
```

That gives me the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  START:
            [header] =>     START:
            [1] =>  START:
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  START:
            [header] =>     START:
            [1] =>  START:
        )

)
```

But as soon as I uncomment the lines

`. '^(.*A: \d{3} B: \d{3}.*)$'`

and

`. '(.*C: \d{3} D: \d{3}.*)$'`

I get no match!

How can I extract this data?

I've tried deleting the start of line anchor `^` and changing the end of line anchor `$` to `\n` with no success

## IN GENERAL

How can I extract the data when I have a **start of data** line followed by n data lines, followed by a **end of data line** followed by **one or more empty lines?**

Comment: When you use the multi-line flag `m` it means that `^` denotes the beginning of the input and `$` denotes the end of the input, not the end of a line.

Comment: @Sammitch m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string), well according to: regex101.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(START)\s+(A:\s+\d+\s+B:\d+)\s+(C:\s+\d+\s+D:\d+)
```

---

**MATCHES:**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-5]   `START`
2.  [6-18]  `A: 567 B:345`
3.  [19-31] `C: 345 D:485`
MATCH 2
1.  [34-39] `START`
2.  [40-52] `A: 345 B:267`
3.  [53-65] `C: 980 D:054`
```

---

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV6aD9/1)
[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/bjBJx7)

Answer (score 1):

While matching multiline string with modifier `m (MULTILINE`, you have to make sure you are matching following newline with `[\r\n]` or better with `\R`.

For your input following regex should work:

```
/^(?<header>START)$\R+^(?<line1>A:\h*\d{3}\h+B:\h*\d{3})$\R+^(?<line2>C:\h*\d{3}\h+D:\h*\d{3})$/m
```

`\R` matches any newline and `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace in PCRE.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hV6aD9/3)